# How to display the separate graph using multiple axios request with React?

Tags: reactjs, axios, victory-charts

I have tried using the multiple axios request to display the graph data for each distinct topic but the result achieved was the graph display all are the same as shown in the screenshot below, it display for the last data only, here is the coding:

```
componentDidMount() {
axios.get(`http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/messages/gettopic`) 
  .then(res => {
    const graphDataName = res.data.map(topics=>{
      axios.get('http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/messages?filter[where][topic]=' + topics + "&filter[order]=timestamp%20DESC")
      .then(res => {
        const graphData = res.data;
        this.setState({graphData});
      })
    });
  })
}

render() {
const { getDeviceListPending, getDeviceListError } = this.props.dashboard;
//const { getDevicePending, getDeviceError } = this.props.dashboard;
//const temperatureData = this.getTempData();
console.log(this.state.graphData);
//console.log(this.state.topics);
return (
  <div className="chart">
    <div className="column">
      <div className="panel">
        {
          this.props.dashboard.listData.map(item=>
            <div className="columns is-multiline">
              <div className="column is-12">
                <div className="panel">
                  <div className="panel-block">
                    <li key={item}>
                      <a key={item} onClick={memobind(this, 'handleRowClick', item)}>
                        {item}
                          <GetChart graphData={this.state.graphData}/>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image: the graph display]

The result of the "this.state.graphData" was showing the data for each distinct topic at here, but the graph display all are the same, I want display each graph data for each device's graph, may I know how to do with it? Thank you. The chart is using Victory Chart and it is using React.

[image: this.state.graphData results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using same state for all graphs.

That's how state tree and updates will be for current scenario:

1. You do call for top level api and get response then you do map and call for graph data. `graphData: {}`
2. You got back 1st graph data and called setState. `graphData: {<graph object for 1st iteration>}`. Before you got this 2nd iteration was also in progress.
3. Now you get back 2nd iteration data. (here issue you will get) you do setState. `graphData: {<graph object for 2nd iteration>}` so here you are replacing first iteration data to next iteration data but this should be an **array** or all should be **different stat**e object so you will push data into that and preserve old iteration graph data.

Example:

```
Initial state -> graphData: []
1st iteration -> graphData: this.state.graphData.concat(res.data).
```

And in render you have to map though graphData and return graph component.

Same way for all the iteration
I hope this might help

```
state = {
  graphData: []
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/messages/gettopic`) 
    .then(res => {
      res.data.map(topic => {
        axios.get('http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/messages?filter[where][topic]=' + topic + "&filter[order]=timestamp%20DESC")
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({graphData: this.state.graphData.concat({topic: topic, data: res.data})});
        })
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
  const { getDeviceListPending, getDeviceListError } = this.props.dashboard;
  //const { getDevicePending, getDeviceError } = this.props.dashboard;
  //const temperatureData = this.getTempData();
  // console.log(this.state.graphData);
  //console.log(this.state.topics);
  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <div className="column">
        <div className="panel">
          {
            this.state.graphData.length && this.state.graphData.map((item, index) =>
              <div className="columns is-multiline" key={index}>
                <div className="column is-12">
                  <div className="panel">
                    <div className="panel-block">
                      <li>
                        <a onClick={memobind(this, 'handleRowClick', item)}>
                          <span>{item.topic}</span>
                          <GetChart graphData={item.data}/>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
            )
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and may I know how to do with it to solve this problem? Can you provide any example code? thank you.

Comment: ok but i need some info first

1. what is `props.dashboard.listData` need some example values
2. will there always be 3 graphs or it depends on `dashboard.listData` or something else??

Comment: 1. oh, that one is actually same with the result come from this API "http://192.168.10.124:3000/api/messages/gettopic" which is for display the different topic name only. 2. that will add the different device in the future so not only 3 graphs. 3. graphs is depend on graphData only.

Comment: Hi, now I want to make the graph in real time data graph, I have this code but dunno how to combine the code with the code you provided to become a real time graph. Can you help me about this? Thank you. The code:
    const { endpoint } = this.state;
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => this.setState({ response: data }));